# Asp classic retrieve querystring after rewrite

Tags: authentication, mod-rewrite, asp-classic, query-string

I decided to make ASP classic user sessionID store into URL QueryString as

1. Cookies is not save enought and needs to be enabled in users browsers
2. Sessions in ASP classic not recommended to use when site have more than 100 users, also ASP append new sessioniD on each request and ASPSESSIONIDS is growing in cookies on each request

So now after user login i generate serverside SID and put it to URL so i get url like

`http://www.example.com/?lang=EN&SID=00C04FB1625D`

And i can get now variables to my script by using Request.QueryString("SID")

But now i need to make human readable URL format and i want to rewrite 
this
`http://www.example.com/?lang=EN&SID=00C04FB1625D`
to this
`http://www.example.com/EN/00C04FB1625D/`

So question is:

1. How to rewrite url in ASP classic in all (10.000) pages?
2. How to retrieve rewrited values from URL?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624349/classic-asp-url-rewriting

Comment: i need rewrite in reverse order

Comment: The above link should provide a template for rewriting from any pattern to any pattern. See the configuration regular expressions for guidance.

Comment: What url rewriting means is that the server will read, for example `http://yoururl.com/article/1` as `http://yoururl.com/article.asp?id=1` - so you don't have to do anything else to retrieve querystring values.  Assuming you have IIS 7 or above you can use the Rewrite module as mjw suggests - take a look at Microsoft's own guide. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module . (If you're on IIS 6 you need to look at third party components - like this one http://iirf.codeplex.com/)