# How to 'cloak' or 'rename' page name/location/url for user but still allow external site to correctly read the true url via HTTP_REFERER

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

My website has a partnership with external sites for members that allows access. The only way our members can access the external site is first if they are authenticated on our site, and then if they visit the external site from a specific page. Such as:

Our partner/external site checks `HTTP_REFERER` and verifies that the user is coming from the exact URL above and then allows them access.

So, we are stuck with this URL unless we request the partner change the URL on their side as well, which is a long complicated process.

I would like to make this URL prettier, but allow the external site to view the correct or "true" URL when the do an `HTTP_REFERER` so that they can still allow access for authenticated users from our site.

Some notes on my specific situation:

1. I am running pages on an IIS 7 Server.
2. Pages are .asp pages and utilizing Classic ASP VB server-side language.
3. I do not have access
       to change anything on the external server checking the `HTTP_REFERER`
       location.

I have tried doing:

```
 <% Server.Transfer("/mynewpage/") %>
```

and that works in the sense that it makes the URL prettier while keeping the page at the same location. But the external site also reads the page as coming from "www.example.org/mynewpage/", which "breaks" our authentication because it's not the predefined page they are looking for to check authentication.

Is there another way that I can "cloak" or "rename" my URL to make it prettier, while still allowing the external site to correctly read the "True" URL when they do an `HTTP_REFERER`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classic ASP URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624349/classic-asp-url-rewriting)

Answer (score 2):

If your host has the URL rewrite module installed (which they probably will) then you can put rewrite rules into the system.webserver section of web.config eg

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="ArticleDetail" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^article/([^/]+)/?$"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.asp?id={R:1}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Articles" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^articles$"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="articles.asp"/>
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

This is for standard  master/detail pages called articles.asp and article.asp.  `yoururl/articles` will find articles.asp and `yoururl/article/30` will find articles.asp?id=30

The alternative is to set up a custom 404 page and use `server.transfer` in that. You would also use web.config to define your 404 page, but the rewrite engine is easier IMO.  Using either approach, both the "pretty" URL and the original url would find the page.

Note that if you have IIS installed on your own machine you can use the Rewrite rule creator in that.  When you use it you'll find that it's added the rules it created to web.config

Comment: Thank you @John! This is very informative. I'm not sure I still 100% understand since I am just finding out this feature exists. I checked our web server, which I do have access to, and it does have Rewrite extension installed.

In my situation, my physical .asp page resides at: www.example.com/this/page/section/legal/important.asp

I would like to be able to give users this link: www.example.com/pubs/legal

and have it go to that page I referenced above. This directory structure does not physically exist. I have tried that setup and it's not working for me.

Comment: Does the "pretty" URL that you give out to users have to exist physically on the server for the rewrite to work? I did this for pattern: ^important\.asp$

And I did this for Rewrite URL: /pubs/legal

But when I try to go to www.example.com/pubs/legal I get a file not found 404 error

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I am updating the web.config at the root level, which I assume is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, use the root level web.config.  The physical directory structure doesn't have to exist on the server - in fact that's the whole point of url rewriting

Comment: For the example you suggested you would use `<match url="^pubs/legal$"/>` and `<action type="Rewrite" url="this/page/section/legal/important.asp"/>`

Comment: I recommend you do a bit of background reading.  Here's a good place to start. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-amodule/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: thank you! Yes, I did do background reading once you pointed me in the right direction and I did follow that article, but as you noticed, I was incorrectly reversing my match URL and rewrite URL. I appreciate your help! Sometimes more assistance is needed even after reading step by step articles and I'm glad this is working now!

Comment: Edit: This has helped me correctly make my URL 'pretty', but unfortunately, this solution does not meet my other requirement of the "external site" seeing the "true URL" for authentication.

Comment: The other bit can't be done.  "Pretty" urls obfuscate the server architecture and that's often why people use them. Google "asprox botnet".  Basically any website which has urls containing ".asp?" is going to be hit with a sql injection attempt by asprox at some point.  Url rewriting isn't enough on its own to protect against sql injection but it helps.  You're going to have to tell your partner to expect referrals from different urls I'm afraid, there's no way round this one.