# IIS: Rewrite / Redirect

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I've searched for this, but to be honest it's hard to put it down in few words for the search engines. I'm old school, so I use ASP Classic on IIS.

I need to create some friendly URL's so I've edited my showPost.asp?id=X to domain.com/X (so the ID is straight after domain name.

After that I have some categories that needs to be divided into a menu so posts inside of that category shows. Now I've tried 2 things:

domain.com/category/bananas

and

domain.com/bananas

If I use the first one, everything on the page thinks the file is inside a folder called category. The URL is domain.com/category.asp?category=bananas

If I use the last one, I suddenly can't use the page category.asp because both queries comes straight after domain.com. Whatever rule is first in web.config will work - the other won't.

I've tried to think of a way to beat it, but I can't. So I ended up here. Hopefully somebody can help my old school mind out!

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classic ASP URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1624349)

Comment: IIS and ASP require ?param=value because that is the way it works. What you are trying to do does not belong on a Windows server and trying to use URLrewrite to change that is futile.